# "FileReadingTools" not working in JAVA

Tags: java

```
// Specify the full path to your file in here.
String datafile = "/home/rez/Desktop/data_example.txt";

double[][] mydata = FileReadingTools.getDoubleArray(datafile);
```

FileReadingTools gives an error
I want a tool to read a text file on my desktop as you can see

Comment: first hit on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file

Comment: Which `FileReadingTools`? Any source code or reference to a library? Second, which error does it provide, any stacktrace?

Comment: Please spend a little more effort in your questions...

Comment: I couldnt find the source code, it is an example code I read somewhere, but it doesnt seem to be working in my program, the error is "cannot find symbol"

Comment: I just need a piece of code to read a text file on my computer

Comment: just follow my link, mate

Comment: @huidube  tnx,I followed your link, but the answers are so different and I couldnt really find a simple code to read a text file

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
public void read() {
    String fileName = "your/path/yourFile.txt";

    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                Charset.defaultCharset());
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```